# Create a numerical expression from multiple elements

Tags: r

I would like to create a vector to use as x-axis in my graph. The vector should have 504 rows and I have created it with the following command.

```
> x=504:1
> p=(1/x):504
Warning message:
In (1/x):504 : numerical expression has 504 elements: only the first used
```

Thus I have first created a variable x that consists of 504 elements. I then wish for the variable p to also consist of 504 elements that are based on each element of x. That is, the first element of P should be 1/504, the second element should be 1/503 ... 1/1. But as you see R only uses the first element in x and neglects the other.

Any clues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need

```
p=(1/x)
```

and that's it. `(1/x)` will take the reciprocal of every element in `x`, and return a 504-element array.  You're confusing R by giving the `:` operator an array as an argument.  It does what it thinks is best, and uses the first element.